# How to resize my Window Form when i get a Bidimensional array of Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a BiDimensional Array of Buttons in my Window Form and i need to resize, because if the number of lines is higher than 10 the buttons of index 9 is not visible on form.

Thanks.

[image: Image Below of my Form]

Comment: `form.Size =  new Size(form.Width, (number_of_buttons * button_height) + spacing);`, or use [AutoSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx)

Comment: Thanks alot Bro! I used this.

`this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 415);`
`this.Height = Coluna * 63;`

Answer (score 1):

Put the buttons on a `FlowLayoutPanel` and set `FlowDirection` of the panel to `TopDown` and set `WrapContents` of the panel to `true`.

Comment: Or do you want to increase the height of the form based on how many buttons there are?

Comment: I just want to increase the height